# unable to get user profile info from microsoft graph api

Tags: azure, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, php-curl

I decided to create app from old azure portal and set the app to multi tenant.
I have set the OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token) for token and OAuth 2.0 authorization endpoint (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize) for authorization.
here is my code for authorization:
    header('location:https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost/xxxxxxx/contacts/connectOffice');

and this is my code for fetching token:

```
$data = array (
      'code' => $code,
      'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=',
      'client_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
      'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/xxxxxx/contacts/connectOffice',
      'scope' =>'offline_access Contacts.ReadWrite'
    );
    $url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);      
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
```

This is the result I get from the token request:

> Array (
>       [token_type] => Bearer
>       [expires_in] => 3599
>       [ext_expires_in] => 0
>       [expires_on] => 1487828228
>       [access_token] => AQABAAAAAADRNYRQ3dhRSrm-4K-adpCJ2ghMrdr3JJCVtGDvxtmOEHcFyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxvU_o8Ob_GixKxnHPPCAA
>       [refresh_token] => AQABAAAAAADRxxxxxxxxxxx0EwuR_igY5qiAA
>       [id_token] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFaxpRFq48A
>   )

I am using this access token which I am using to send a GET request to access Microsoft graph api(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me) for getting user profile. This is my get request:

```
$url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';
$headers = array(     
        "Authorization: Bearer ".$access_token                 
      );
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );               
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');              
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);               
$response=curl_exec($ch);
```

I am getting this error :

> Array (
>       [error] => Array
>           (
>               [code] => InvalidAuthenticationToken
>               [message] => CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105
>               [innerError] => Array
>                   (
>                       [request-id] => 43eae80b-c3f0-4909-a71d-4e5d3d982579
>                       [date] => 2017-02-22T15:09:25
>                   )

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong ?

Comment: Can you share the contents of the token after you remove personal information?

Comment: and also include the entire request - how do you request the token from the token endpoint.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi  I have added the token in my question

Comment: @astaykov I have added the full request code for authorization,tokens and reading user profile

Comment: Sorry, I mean can you decode the token for us. Use a site like [this](http://calebb.net/).

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi when I am trying to decode my access token or refresh token  from the link you have provided it says "JWT is required to have three segments"

Comment: but when I decode my Id token it gives me this :{
 typ: "JWT",
 alg: "RS256",
 x5t: "_UgqXG_tMLduSJ1T8caHxU7cOtc",
 kid: "_UgqXG_tMLduSJ1T8caHxU7cOtc"
}.
{
 aud: "8adfad2b-f28a-40a6-8698-8b53ac506100",
 iss: "https://sts.windows.net/49322bd9-93ea-4911-a8e4-1aa10bc5b680/",
 iat: 1487828709,
 nbf: 1487828709,
 exp: 1487832609,
 amr: [
  "pwd"
 ],

Comment: and 
 family_name: "OrgName",
 given_name: "Tester",
 ipaddr: "115.187.45.131",
 name: "Tester ORrName",
 oid: "60d91a14-cb6f-450c-be5e-08aa47e22283",
 platf: "3",
 sub: "gxgOuC2fJ7bNbfqQRCPIi6lkm0QgN2YnUymBFdyzH0Q",
 tid: "49322bd9-93ea-4911-a8e4-1aa10bc5b680",
 unique_name: "xxxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
 upn: "xxx@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
 ver: "1.0"
}.
[signature]

Comment: You should be able to decode the access token also. Perhaps it has gotten truncated or mangled somehow.

Comment: @RasmusW can you suggest what might be causing this ?

Comment: Assuming you have correctly registered your application and granted it access to the Microsoft Graph, try with changing the `scope` in your request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`.